# When laravel schedule Monthly() exactly Run?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks, schedule

i have create one command and set it to run on every month like

> $schedule->command('send-reports')
>           ->monthly();

Now my Question is when it's Run exactly ??

**At start of month like `2019-02-01 00:00:00` OR At end of month `2019-01-31 11:59:59`**

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php#L506). Function return '0 0 1 * * *', which translates to 'at 00:00 on day-of-month 1'.

Comment: Thanks Sir !, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

when you schedule a task using the `->monthly()` method, it will run on the first day of every month at 00:00. If you need the task to run at a specific time other than midnight, you can use the `->monthlyOn()` method instead, which allows you to specify the day of the month and the time the task should run. For example, `->monthlyOn(4, '15:00')` will schedule the task to run every month on the 4th at 3:00 PM​​​​.

Keep in mind that the actual time the task runs can be influenced by the server's timezone setting, so you may need to set the desired timezone using the `->timezone('TimeZone')` method if it's different from the server's default timezone